# EMF Induced Between Parallel Conductors

Tags: electromagnetism

If two conductors (A and B), separated by a distance R, are parallel for a length ℓ and conductor B has an AC current flowing through it (I), what would be the equation to calculate the EMF (voltage) induced in conductor A between points 1 and 2.

To help clarify the question, I will give the following example inputs:

- Conductor B is AWG 4 (5 mm) diameter single core cable. (It is carrying an AC current of 10 A (RMS) @ 50 Hz)
- Conductor A is an 8 mil wide 1 oz PCB copper trace
- The length ℓ between points 1 and 2 is 50 mm
- The gap between the centre of the conductors A and B (R) is 5 mm
- A complete path (not shown in the diagram) exists such that current can flow in conductor A
- The medium between the conductors is air

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Isn't this just an application of Lenz's Law?

Comment: No but it is an invalid question !!! without specs for Rload, frequency , conductor geometry , frequency, skin effects gap to nearby ground planes etc etc......-1

Comment: try the Maxwellian form using  Telegrapher's Equations for Coupled Transmission Lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider first that the two wires (of length \$\ell\$) are placed very close to each other such that the distance R is very small (ostensibly zero). Consider also that the driven wire has self-inductance (L) and that this inductance has a reactance that develops a volt drop due to the current flowing: -

[image]

Because the two wires (driven and undriven) are very close, we can assume the field generated by the driven wire is wholly shared by the undriven wire and so we get 100% transformer action and, whatever voltage is across the length (\$\ell\$) of the driven wire will be (in fact has to be) across the receiving wire.

The voltage is \$I\cdot\omega L\$ and that voltage rapidly gets smaller as R increases. But, what is the inductance of a wire: -

[image]

However, you can use an [online calculator](https://www.eeweb.com/tools/wire-inductance) for that to get the answer if you don't want a math/algebra solution: -

[image]

So that gives you the induced voltage when R is zero. To calculate the voltage when R is non-zero requires understanding of how the coupled flux falls away with an increasing distance R.

This is probably best understood by thinking about how the flux density falls away with distance from a long straight conductor (based on [Biot Savart](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/Biosav.html)).

Flux density, B = \$\dfrac{\mu_0\cdot I}{2\pi d}\$

Where I is the current and d is the distance from the conductor. If this is integrated from d=0 to d=infinity, you get the total flux and this of course is used to calculate wire inductance as indicated at the top of the answer.

If you then integrate only as far as distance R you get the flux that **isn't** coupled to the receiving wire. The difference between the two is the flux that couples to the receiving wire and, as a proportion of the total flux that is the coupling factor, k: -

[image]

So, you calculate k (based on distance R) and that multiples by the voltage across the driven inductance/wire to give the induced emf.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83903/discussion-on-answer-by-andy-aka-emf-induced-between-parallel-conductors).

Comment: This is still not a correct answer unless wavelength or frequency and all the inductive phy. Specs (missing) are given. EMF=0 as given. WHere is the OP anyways? (Hiding)  Give a measurable answer with all parameters if you disagree.  Your answer computes flux but not voltage in a open conductor. YOur answer computes inductance but without current and Phy and frequency, there is no VOLTAGE. Or EMF

Comment: You don’t know what you are talking about tony.

Comment: @Andyaka, I still can't see how the total flux is not infinite (see chat). Can you explain where I am wrong?

Comment: @ChrisBrown Maybe a different approach to finding the total flux is needed. For a single wire, as far as I remember, the inductance is defined as flux (not flux density) per amp. So re-arranging, total flux = inductance x current. This possibly solves the infinities in the equation and permits a sensible calculation of flux from close to the wire to R. I'm a bit rusty on the integration of the Biot Savart relationship so sorry I can't be more helpful at this time. Another possible route is to address this specific part of the question (calculating total flux) on the physics part of SE.

Comment: 1 Weber is equivalent to 1 Henry-Amp so I believe that formula holds as long as there is only a single loop. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ChrisBrown Give it a go and let me know what the numbers are for total flux and the total flux from driven wire to R. Interesting.

Comment: Would this answer still be valid if the inductance of the two conductors are not equal? (i.e. the mutual inductance does not equal the inductance of conductor B)

Comment: The answer is only valid over the common length of the two wires. If wire B is longer than wire A then you must calculate the inductance of wire B over the common length. Did you post anything on physics.se?

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the magnetic rate of flux change induced by the conductor B between the distance R and infinity.

The emf induced in conductor A  = N d(phi)/dt. Here N =1, because there is only a single wire. phi is the magnetic flux enclosed by the conductor A.

The current you have provided is 10 Amperes. This is an RMS value, I assume. The peak value, assuming it is a sine wave is = sqrt(2)*10 = 14.41 Amps.

The equation of the current flow in A = 14.41* sin(wt), where w = 2*pi*f *t, f is in HZ (or cycles per second). You have not specified the frequency. Also, the medium in which the conductors are situated. You have to account for the magnetic permeability of the medium.

Here is a python program that calculates the voltage between points 1 and 2:

"""
Python program to calculate the voltage induced in a wire
by another parallel wire, both of finite length.

The formula given above appears to be wrong.
It is possible for the self inductance.
What we need here is a formula for the MUTUAL inductance.
Formula for the mutual inductance is:

M = mu_0 * 2*l*[ ln[(l/d)+ sqrt{1 + (l^2/d^2) -{sqrt[1 + [d^2/l^2]] + d/l}

mu _{0}= 4π × 10−7   Comment:N·A−2 (Permeability of free space)

This formula can be obtained from:

1. Professor Marc Anderson: http://www.thompsonrd.com/induct2.pdf
2. Frederic W. Grover, Inductance Calculations, Dover Publications.

where l = length of the parallel wires, and d is the separation between the wires.

Here, we are assuming that both the parallel wires are of the same length.

In the problem above, d = R.

The current = 10 Amperes. Since the problem states, it is AC,
we are going to assume it is sinusoidal and 60 hz.

The voltage induced between terminals 1 and 2 of conductor A is:

v = M di/dt volts.

The instantaneous current in conductor B is:

i = IMax sin(wt), where, w = 2*pi.f, f in hz, and t in seconds.

di/dt = IMax *w*cos(wt)

f =60 in the United States.
IMax = sqrt(2) *10 
di/dt = sqrt(2) * 10 *2.0*pi*60* cos(wt)
The procedure we are going to adopt is to calculate
the peak voltage first and then attach the cos(wt) to it.

"""
import math

## The Maximum value of I_prime = di/dt = math.sqrt(2)*10.0 *2.0*math.pi*60.0

I_prime_max = math.sqrt(2)*10.0 *2.0*math.pi*60.0

print(I_prime_max)

## I_prime_max = 5331.459525790039 Amps = Approximately 5331.46 Amps

## Let us calculate the mutual inductance M:

Since no values are given for L and D,
the induced voltage between terminals 1 and 2 is :
= M* 5331.459525790039* cos(wt),
where M is the value of the mutual inductance given by M above.
To attach some numerical values, let the length of the wires = 1 meter,
the distance of separation be = 0.5 meters.
 M = mu_0*2*l*[ ln[(l/d)+ sqrt{1 + (l^2/d^2) -{sqrt[1 + [d^2/l^2]] + d/l}

mu_0 = 4* math.pi*10^(-7)

^ stands for exponentiation. * stands for multiplication.
l = 1.0
d = 0.5
a = l/d
print("a = ", a)
b = d/l
print("b =", b)
M = mu_0*2.0* l *[math.log[a1 + math.sqrt[1 + (a1)^2]] - math.sqrt[1 + (a2)^2] + a2]

A = math.log(a + math.sqrt(1 + a^2))

print("A = ", A)

B = math.sqrt(1 + b^2)

print("B = ", B)

M = mu_0*(2.0 *l*A - B + b)

print(M, 'Henrys')

M = 2.851607267136502e-06 Henrys

V_peak =  M * 5331.46

print("The peak voltage between points 1 and 2 =",V_peak )

print("The RMS Voltage between points 1 and 2 =" , V_peak/math.sqrt(2), "Volts")

The peak voltage between points 1 and 2 = 0.015203230080447576
The RMS Voltage between points 1 and 2 = 0.010750307085823781 Volts
or, the RMS(Root Mean Square) Voltage between points 1 and 2 = 10.75 milli-volts.

Comment: hey Assume \$\mu_R=\epsilon_R=1\$ and 1.414 and for f, assume wavelength far greater than geometry shown and L>>R

Comment: To: Solar Mike: This is Faraday's law of induction.

Comment: Bandwidth or rise time is critical to the answer not yet displayed

Comment: or as Gauss once said "theorie der Strahlung"

Comment: There is no current flow in A and your answer doesn’t appear to take account of the distance between the two conductors nor their length.

Comment: 10 A was indeed intended to be an RMS current although this was just an example number to indicate the expected range. The expected frequency is 50/60 Hz. It should be assumed that the medium in which the conductors are situated is air. I presume the calculation of the magnetic flux density would take into account the distance between the conductors. And the length taken into account when calculating the flux contained within conductor A.

Comment: @AndyAka: From the diagram, l = L. Also, the formula for B you have given is for the flux density, which is the flux per unit area. The formula you have given is for the flux density at a midway point (L/2 = l/2).  To get the flux enclosed is B multiplied by area da. Please note that B varies at every point. Thus you cannot integrate B. you need to integrate B.(da). It is actually a double integral, parallel to the wire and perpendicular to the wire. The diagrams are very nice indeed!

Comment: I did mention that in a comment to the op but I shall check how clear I made that in my answer. I don't understand when you say " From the diagram, l = L"?????

Answer (score 0):

Assume \$\mu_R=\epsilon_R=1\$  and there are no other conductors nearby ( which could shunt the mutual inductance.)

Use double integral Neumann formula to get Mutual Inductance

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductance#Mutual_inductance_of_two_parallel_straight_wires

then V or EMF=Ldi/dt which say for 0.1 ns is 100% of applied EMF in crosstalk in practical terms where R < < L  in geometry

The missing load R and wire inductance on each side control the rise time T+L/R for a step load current. So you can define dI/dt yourself, where 10~90% rise time  dt=0.35/f(-3dB BW) approx.

I leave the re-search for your homework.

## Remember

Wavelength is reduced with dt  ( especially in ns range for short wires )   and antenna theory takes over for geometry > 5% wavelength for reflection coefficients, mismatched impedances and resulting effects on EMF or voltage crosstalk.

Comment: You don’t need R on the load side to calculate the open circuit induced emf.

Comment: you dont have current with an open circuit unless using antenna theory and impedance of air

Comment: Precisely and the op isn’t asking for current. Read the question!

Comment: but that is ambiguous as there are no specs for current BW , frequency or impedance  E Field coupling or EMF induced B fields matter. here  But if you have the exact answer pls tell us.

Comment: @Andyaka  tell me what is the EMF if current is 50 Hz or 3GHz, 0.1ns rise time? any difference? use any assumptions for L,R etc  0V?  Read the question!

Comment: I don't have an exact answer because that does depend somewhat on skin-depth a la frequency but I do have an answer.

Comment: @Andyaka Would it not be 0V with 10A if the resistance is assumed to be 0 ohms as shown and the AC is like 50 or 60 Hz?

Comment: What has resistance got to do with induction?

Comment: Both produce a voltage (  term for EMF) but if the inductance is negligble (10nH @60Hz) and the resistance is similar < 1 milliohm  What is your answer on EMF produced with 10A?  ( essentially Zero)  catch my drift? @Andyaka this question has no details so it is a trick question

Comment: If the wires are so short to give make 10 nH then the volt drop is virtually zero. No it isn’t a trick question; short wires induce very little at low frequencies.

Comment: Ok so you agree with my answer V=0, maybe the silent questioner means Magnetic force between conductors but then it is not EMF but the force from a magnetic field.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ZERO Ohm conductors and low-frequency AC current on the right then the voltage on the left, EMF=0 because of Resistance = 0 Ω from Ohms Law.  ( an overlooked assumption)

Nobody measures by "EMF" in practice.

The international standards are in Volts.

This is a silly academic learning question.

Comment: Assuming an 8 mil 1oz copper PCB trace (resistance < 1 ohm). Assuming the AC current is 50/60 Hz. I am looking for an answer in volts. I'm sorry the question is silly (I'm a little out of my depth) but this answer wasn't helpful at all.

Comment: Conductor B would be a cable of diameter suitable to carry 10 A RMS

Comment: yes and it is assumed to be very low resistance for low line loss so if no resistance is given, may we assume this dumb .. erhm I mean trick academic question that it is 0 Ohms @ChrisBrown given the gross lack of details